# I'm trying to change the pitch of my recorded but getting the error in readBytesResult

Tags: objective-c, caf, pitch-shifting

i m referring the example in the http://devnulldb.blogspot.in/2012/07/how-to-set-up-openal-and-play-sound.html

can anyone help me please

```
UInt32 bytesRead = (UInt32)fileSizeInBytes;
void* audioData = malloc(bytesRead);



OSStatus readBytesResult = AudioFileReadBytes(afid, false, 0, &bytesRead, audioData);

// "here I'm getting the value of readBytesResult -39"

if (0 != readBytesResult) {
    NSLog(@"An error occurred when attempting to read data from audio file %@: %ld", _url, readBytesResult);
}
```

Comment: You got a `kAudioFileEndOfFileError` error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948741/audiofilereadbytes-error ?

Comment: that page does not have any solution of that particular problem can you help me to get out of this problem ???